# ios github undeclared identifier AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

I have created a repo of my project in Github, i used AFNetworking cocoapod in my project. When i download my project from github and tried to run in xcode, it raises errors like 'undeclared identifier AFHTTPRequestOperation'

Could anyone please help me in resolving this issues.

Comment: Make sure to install the pods back to load the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have not pushed your pod projects to the repo.

Go to you project/pod directory and run the command

`pod install`

For future remove pod from the `.gitignore` file if any.

---

If the problem still persist then edit you pod file and add

`pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5`

then run the same command

`pod install`